# How to install application from Xcode on iOS 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I did the following things:

- Click Product - Archive in Xcode
- On the created archive, click Show in Finder
- Open ./AppName 13-07-2017, 18.15.xcarchive/Products/Applications/
- Drag AppName.app to iTunes
- Install the app on a device

But it doesn't install. I tried to do this thing on iOS 8 device and it worked, but on iOS 10 the app just disappears when upload is done. On iOS 11 Beta 2 it shows error "Unable To Install AppName" - "This app could not be installed."

How it could be fixed?

I built the app for Release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the archive, you don't want to Show in Finder. You should click on the Export button on the right side of the organizer. This will give you a panel with four options. You probably want to select the 2nd one, "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment". Choose where to put the app and use that one with iTunes to install.